# Bounding box for connected region in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

```
Iprops = regionprops(cl,'BoundingBox');
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox];

[m,n]=size(Ibox);

Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 (n/4)]);

figure,imshow(image);

hold on;
for cnt = 1:n/4
rectangle('position',Ibox(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
end
```

**Error**

Error using rectangle
Value must be a 4 element vector

Error in detecttext (line 49)

```
 rectangle('position',Ibox(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making it a row instead of a column:

```
Ibox(:,cnt).'
```